# Error : undefined local variable or method `post' for #<PostsController:0x3a5cba0>"

Tags: rails-migrations

i have come across problem in adding links to posts.
**`My code for index is :-`**

```
<h1>Listing posts</h1>
<%= link_to 'new post',new_post_path %>
<table>
<tr>
<th>title </th>
<th>text</th>
</tr>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<tr>
<td> <%= post.title %> </td>
<td><%= post.text %> </td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
<h1> hello rails </h1>
<%= link_to "my blog",controller: "posts" %>
<p>Find me in app/views/welcome/index.html.erb</p>
```

**`my code for post_controller is:-`**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def index
@posts=post.all
end
def new
end
def create
@post=Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title,:text))
@post.save
redirect_to @post
#render text: params[:post].inspect
end
def show
@post=Post.find(params[:id])
end
private
def post_params
params.require(:post).permit(:title,:text)
end
end
```

The error that is shown is  "undefined local variable or method `post' for #"
Please help me out to trace the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your code of method `index` in **PostsController**:

It should be:

```
def index
@posts=Post.all
end
```

Instead of:

```
def index
@posts=post.all
end
```

Check:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

This doc clearly says:

Open `app/controllers/posts_controller.rb` and inside the `PostsController` class, define a new method like this:

```
def new
end
```

With the new method defined in PostsController, if you refresh you'll see another error:

```
Template is missing.
```

You're getting this error now because Rails expects plain actions like this one to have views associated with them to display their information. With no view available, Rails errors out.

Read the document to understand and try to resolve it yourself by associating some view to the method. 
Its too easy, the rails way.

Comment: what's the last line for ? Remove this line `<p>Find me in app/views/welcome/index.html.erb</p>`

Comment: when i click the link "back" for showing the list ..it shows the error "template missing"